# How do i apply color to a textbox in GridView?

Tags: android, android-studio, gridview, palette

I'm creating a wallpaper app and I want to apply `getLightMutedColor()`of Palette class to the textbox below each wallpaper. But It's creating problems on restarting the app .

**So this is how it should be**

[image: So this is how it should be]

**On restarting the app the color changes to white**

[image: On restarting the app the color changes to white]

Here's my adapter class

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<GridItem> {

private Context mContext;
private int layoutResourceId;
private ArrayList<GridItem> mGridData = new ArrayList<GridItem>();

public GridViewAdapter(Context mContext, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<GridItem> mGridData) {
    super(mContext, layoutResourceId, mGridData);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mGridData = mGridData;
}


/**
 * Updates grid data and refresh grid items.
 * @param mGridData
 */
public void setGridData(ArrayList<GridItem> mGridData) {
    this.mGridData = mGridData;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.titleTextView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_title);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    GridItem item = mGridData.get(position);
    holder.titleTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(item.getTitle()));
    Picasso.with(mContext)
            .load(item.getImage())
            .into(new Target() {
                @Override
                public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                    Palette p = Palette.from(bitmap).generate();
                    int defaultColor= 0x000000;
                    int vbcol = p.getLightMutedColor(defaultColor);
                    holder.titleTextView.setBackgroundColor(vbcol);
                }

                @Override
                public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

                }
            });
    Picasso.with(mContext).load(item.getImage()).into(holder.imageView);
    return row;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView titleTextView;
    ImageView imageView;
}
 }
```

Comment: I never used this, but I think that it may be from this 'int vbcol = p.getLightMutedColor(defaultColor);' can you add a breakpoint and cheack whats wrong?

Comment: I never used breakpoint before. but i tried it and it's showing white background on text boxes.

Comment: I am not trying this but can u try this in AsyncTask....

Answer (score 0):

This is the Asynchronous wayt to do it, You can have a look at this:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/graphics/Palette.html

Try this code, maybe it will work

```
Palette.from(bitmap).generate(new PaletteAsyncListener() {
     public void onGenerated(Palette p) {
         int defaultColor= 0x000000;
         int vbcol = p.getLightMutedColor(defaultColor);
         holder.titleTextView.setBackgroundColor(vbcol);
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Was getting nullpointerexception with everything so it was certain that the image wasn't loaded so i made it work with this callback

```
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable)holder.imageView.getDrawable();
            Bitmap bm =bd.getBitmap();
            Palette p = Palette.from(bm).generate();
            int defcol=0x000000;
            holder.titleTextView.setBackgroundColor(p.getLightVibrantColor(defcol));
        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {

        }
    });
```